# Karma error - No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I just started to use Karma for first time...Following this tutuorial : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html I am writing simple test to check if the title is correct. I always get this **error : "No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/"** .I am using Angular 2 and typescript. These are the versions

```
"@angular/core": "2.4.10" 
"jasmine-core": "^2.6.2",
"karma": "^1.7.0".
```

My folder structure looks like this

```
mydashboard
 -src
   -app
     -welcome
       -welcome.component.ts
       -welcome.component.spec.ts   
 -karma.conf.js

//karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: ["src/app/**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
//welcome.component.spec.ts
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome.component';

describe('WelcomeComponent  (inline template)', () => {
  let comp:    WelcomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WelcomeComponent>;
  let de:      DebugElement;
  let el:      HTMLElement;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ WelcomeComponent  ], // declare the test component
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance; // WelcomeComponent  test instance
    // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
  });

  it('should display original title', () => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(el.textContent).toContain(comp.title);
});
});
//welcome.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>'
})
export class WelcomeComponent {
  title = 'Test Tour of Heroes';
}
```

[image]

Comment: that is just a warning (plus after that chrome starts), your problem is somewhere else, can you provide more input? and you don't have the `plugins` section in your configuration. Something like `plugins: [ 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-chrome-launcher']`. Please change the `logLevel` to `config.LOG_DEBUG`

Comment: @Edwin Thank you. I added plugins and changed logLevel. I get the same warning and error `Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.023 secs / 0 secs)` . I have added additional code samples above. welcome.component.spec.ts and welcome.component.ts

Comment: and now with the new log level, do you get new output? or is the same? and then is the question: do you have these plugins in `node_modules` folder?

Comment: @Edwin I get new debug messages but at the end of line I see this `Chrome 57.0.2987 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.031 secs / 0 secs)
`

Comment: what about my second question? and it seems that it doesn't finds the tests `0 of 0`. We will need more debug info

Comment: @Edwin The plugins are available in node_modules. Now I noticed error in Chrome Console : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` and may be because of this it doesn't find the tests. The tests are not executed and it is Skipped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145638/discussion-between-user1731770-and-edwin).

Comment: @user1731770: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 14):

Some invocations of `fixture.debugElement.query` conflict with later invocations of `expect(...)`, causing a seemingly infinite loop in Jasmine's code.

For example, the following will cause the error when an object that matches `#my-id` exists:

```
expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#my-id'))).toBeFalsy();
```

In your case you had a different combination of calls, but it's the same recipe: `query` plus some `expect` calls.

As a temporary workaround, we can use `queryAll(...).length` instead:

```
expect(fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('#my-id')).length).toBeFalsy();
```

This is a bug in Jasmine, and is already reported in these pages:

- [Here for Jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1263)
- [Here for Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14235)

Comment: Thanks! I was having this exact issue