# How do I unit test if an element is visible when the *ngIf directive is used using Jasmine in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have an Angular 6 app and writing some unit tests trying to determine if an element is visible or not based solely on the boolean result of an `*ngIf` directive.

Markup:

```
<div class="header" *ngIf="show">
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

spec file:

```
it('should hide contents if show is false', () => {
    const button = debugElement.query(By.css('button')).nativeElement;
    button.click();   // this will change show to false
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.header')).nativeElement.style.hidden).toBe(true);
});
```

I can't seem to get the `hidden` attribute from the div.  Does angular use another approach to hiding the  element from the DOM using the `*ngIf` directive?  Do I need to get another property from the `nativeElement`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If the element is hidden, then it wont be rendered inside the dom.

You can check

```
expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.header'))).toBeUndefined();
```

**EDIT** : `toBeNull()` works better in the above case

```
expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.header'))).toBeNull();
```

And also you have a syntax error while fetching the button element. `nativeElement` is not a function.

Change it this way :

```
const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button')).nativeElement;
```

Comment: Ultimately what worked for me was to check the node itself as you did in the first line of this answer.  Interestingly, however, instead of checking `undefined` I ended up checking whether or not the node was `null` using the `toBeNull()` function.  That seemed to work for me.

Comment: Be careful with combining `fixture.debugElement.query` with invocations of `expect(...)`. This can cause Out-Of-Memory errors in the browser. Happened to me.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48606192/2042301

Comment: I had the same question, and this was indeed the correct answer. However, we have (for _some_ reason) not the default change detection: `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.`. It turned out in the browser the element was removed automatically, but in the unit test I had to call the `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()' manually in order to get it to work

Comment: The code here seems to pass for me even when the ngIf evaluates to false...

Answer (score 12):

When testing if a component is being shown or not using `ngIf` I try to get the element (in this case you use, i.e.,  `debugElement.query(By.css('.header')).nativeElement`) and if it should be shown I expect it to be truthy, otherwise falsy.

Something like this:

```
it('should hide contents if show is false', () => {
    // should be rendered initially
    expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.header')).nativeElement).toBeTruthy();
    //trigger change
    const button = debugElement.query(By.css('button')).nativeElement;
    button.click();   // this will change show to false
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // should not be rendered
    expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.header')).nativeElement).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Also, bear in mind that sometimes you need to use [`ComponentFixture#whenStable`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/ComponentFixture#whenStable) to detect when the fixture is stable like this:

```
  it('should hide contents if show is false', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      // same test code here
    });
  });
```

See this **[working test](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/ngiftest/blob/beaa8e92714293f4f5101518b4c2eb7be0122321/src/app/app.component.spec.ts#L14)** for a [component](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/ngiftest/blob/beaa8e92714293f4f5101518b4c2eb7be0122321/src/app/app.component.ts#L10) which [resembles this scenario](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/ngiftest/blob/beaa8e92714293f4f5101518b4c2eb7be0122321/src/app/app.component.html#L1).

See [*[GitHub repository](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/ngiftest)*]

Comment: Shouldn't the second example test function be marked as `async` since we're working with promises there?

Comment: @Werek - As we are not awaiting the promise, but utilizing `then` to head over to callback-world, the function signature does not have to be marked with `async`.

Answer (score 10):

You need add fixture.detectChanges() after you change value of 'show' to true

```
component.show = true;
fixture.detectChanges()
```

Comment: Thank you! In my case, I had an Observable and thus couldn't assign it to be true. I had to mock the observable and assign it to the ```component.thePropertyOnWhichTheConditionDepends```. The ```fixture.detectChanges()``` was the final bit what made the test work!

Answer (score 4):

Writing test case for `*ngIf` condition use `toBeNull` condition.

Try with below code, it works for me.

```
expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.header'))).toBeNull();
```

Answer (score 3):

When using ngIf, angular completely removes the node from markup. So you need to check that this element not exists.

[Documentation says:](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

> ngIf evaluates the expression and then renders the then or else template in its place when expression is truthy or falsy respectively.

To be more precise, it's just not rendered

Comment: thanks!  I also tried to test to see if the nativeElement is undefined and it keeps failing the test saying `Expected HTMLNode to be undefined` so it seems to be checking the value of the node rather than whether or not it exists in the DOM

Comment: @J-man check fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.header')).nativeElement