# Consternation on testing non-inherited-yet-inherited CSS display property

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, jasmine

I have created a modal component in Angular. In a unit test, the modal is appearing in the DOM as shown:
[image]

However, I start out with a style on `app-modal2` that includes `display:none`, so what actually renders is just the fixed text above the modal -- the content of the modal is correctly omitted:
[image]

When the user takes an action that adjusts the style to include `display:block` then the content of the modal correctly appears. Which is to say, the code is working exactly as I expect.

What I am confounded about is a unit test.

So: why my title (*"Consternation on testing non-inherited-yet-inherited CSS display property"*) ?

Well, according to the [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/CRD-css-display-3-20201218/#the-display-properties), the `display` property is NOT inherited:
[image]

Using browser dev tools, I have confirmed that is true: descendant elements have values other than `none` for the `display` property. So even though descendant elements are affected by an ancestor having `display: none` it is because the subtree rooted at the ancestor is removed -- *and this is not considered inheritance*. Well, OK, [potayto, potahto](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/potayto%2C+potahto)... Not technically inherited, but acts like it.

The visibility of my modal is controlled by the `display` property. It is set either to `display: none` or `display:block` depending on user actions. But that is strictly dealing with visibility, not existence. That is, `#myContent` is present with either `display` value. Since I therefore cannot test for existence of `#myContent` I must test strictly for visibility.

So how do I check an element for visibility controlled by some ancestor's `display` value, since `display` is not inherited? Is there a way to check for any ancestor having `display:none`? Or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't checking display properties etc fall under the category of testing implementation details? Could you instead test by searching/querying for the existence in of the text `any content here...`? Or something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/51291842/5385381

Comment: @ksav Good question, but no. In the edits I just made, I explain that that content will always be present.

Comment: I was chagrined to see my question closed prematurely, as I thought I was asking a  clear question. Ah, language. Nevertheless, I have reworded it to, I hope, improve the clarity. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the jQuery [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method, and put the style as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

I found out pretty disturbing your question. I think is one of the most hard questions to answer because goes right to the core of cascading and inheritance.

As far as I could find, display property is the only property that can't be specified (but computed) on how should be display by UA. HTML tags are pre-defined styles, those styles are display on UA without any CSS file, e.g. `p` elements are display as `inline`.

I tested it too with devtools; forgetting JS at all for **very front-end purposes**. (Maybe I'll check with with JS later as -second part-). This answer is intended for all audiences, newbies and experienced *devs*.

Before declare what is going to be styled, we may note that [we have dependencies from the browser](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#the-css-user-agent-style-sheet-and-presentational-hints) (User Agent) that parses the stylesheet.

We do not define all universe of properties to be styled, so when is not defined, a property needs to be set and [the user agent roles to set a property](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#the-css-user-agent-style-sheet-and-presentational-hints) (doesn't have to be its initial value), [there's no official specification on how UA must render websites](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#:%7E:text=User%20agents%20are%20not%20required%20to%20present%20HTML%20documents%20in%20any%20particular%20way), it's expected them to be display [as the stylesheet specifies](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#cascading-origins), which often, does not act likely according browsing experience.

### Cascading

> [One of the fundamental design principles of CSS is cascading.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#cascading)

What does an User Agent (UA) cascades? Elements? Properties? Objects?

Well, UA treat HTML tags as *elements*, and those elements are called as ***[box tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/CRD-css-display-3-20201218/#:%7E:text=Each%20box%20in%20the%20box%20tree%20represents%20its%20corresponding%20element%20(or%20pseudo-element)%20in%20space%20and/or%20time%20on%20the%20canvas)***, as the same, text included inside an element are called as **[text node](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/CRD-css-display-3-20201218/#:%7E:text=while%20each%20text%20run%20in%20the%20box%20tree%20likewise%20represents%20the%20contents%20of%20its%20corresponding%20text%20nodes.)**.

Since CSS syntax and its parsing is a *perfect* ***cascade***, that is the only word that remains if we need to figure out about how (UA) *must* display HTML documents. The UA also applies its own style sheet. This means that rendering also depends on the way (units) we use to specify values, if we specify a lot of different values e.g. pixels, cm, percentages, relative units (em, rem), etc, the more information UA needs to parse to be displayed, that's why front-end developers should be encouraged to perform clean css styles with homogeneous units to squeeze every milisecond out of browsing perfomance (such important in mobile experiences).

### Inheritance

> [When no declarations try to set a the value for an element/property
> combination. In this case, a value is be found by way of inheritance
> or by looking at the property’s initial value.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#:%7E:text=when%20no%20declarations%20try%20to%20set%20a%20the%20value%20for%20an%20element/property%20combination.%20In%20this%20case%2C%20a%20value%20is%20be%20found%20by%20way%20of%20inheritance%20or%20by%20looking%20at%20the%20property%E2%80%99s%20initial%20value)

What is called for inheritance, it's just the css properties that can be inherited (those are already established).

So, if a css property seems to be inherited, it's not really inheritance behavior, it's cascading behavior, and it's inheritance becomes by the nature of the syntax for the specified css property.

### Answer

The display property is not inherited, but when `none` property is set, all the descendants elements will no generate any box-model subtree nor text node, (JS could be forcing the element to be display for testing purposes).

In the case of `display:none;` when the ***[box tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/CRD-css-display-3-20201218/#:%7E:text=Each%20box%20in%20the%20box%20tree%20represents%20its%20corresponding%20element%20(or%20pseudo-element)%20in%20space%20and/or%20time%20on%20the%20canvas)*** and **[text node](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/CRD-css-display-3-20201218/#:%7E:text=while%20each%20text%20run%20in%20the%20box%20tree%20likewise%20represents%20the%20contents%20of%20its%20corresponding%20text%20nodes.)** descendants are hidden by the parent element, the style applied of `none` **is by cascading, not by inheritance**.

[image: Screenshot]

In the example below, the `span` that is descendant of the fourth `div` element has set the background property as *inherit*, but the background can't be inherited, that's why the `span` element does not display any color background. Otherwise, the `span` that is descendant of the third `div` element inherits the `color` property. The fourth `div` element has `display` set: inline; once again, display can't be inherited, that's why the span element does not inherit that property and is displayed as `block` by the UA.

```css
*{
  border: 1px solid black;

}

.one {
  display:block;
}

.two {
  
}

.three{

  background:cornsilk;
}

.childthree{
  color:red;
}

span{
  background: inherit;
  position: relative;
  top:80px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin:5px;
}

.four{
  display:inline;
}

canvas{
  background:#99e6ff;
}

html {
  padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
  <div class="three">three
    <div class="childthree">I'm a subtree inside the third div<br><span>I'm span tag</span></div>
    </div>
  <div class="four">four<p>i'm a p tag with thext content<span>I'm a span element inside a p element</span></p</p>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```